# Do I need to deploy 32bit or 64bit VC++ runtimes for a 32bit Application on a 64bit machine?

Tags: visual-studio, visual-c++, deployment

- I develop a C++ Application with Visual Studio 2015 on a 64bit machine.
- The platform toolset is set to Visual Studio 2015 (v140)
- The code is compiled as 32bit.
- The code uses dynamic runtime libaries (/MD switch), /MT is not an option.
- The target machine also has a 64bit windows installed.

I understood that I need to install the Visual C++ 2015 Redistributable package on the target machine, so that all the required DLLs will be available. However, do I need to install the 32bit or the 64bit runtime (and why)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The exectuable is 32bit, hence you need the 32bit runtime. It will install dlls which are compiled as 32bit, just like your application, and mixing 32bit with 64bit is impossible.